# Pan and zoom to display the query results by using Fusion Table Layer

Tags: javascript, google-fusion-tables

I am beginner in Fusion Table Layer. I would like to display the query results as here (pan and zoom): https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/samples/search_and_zoom ,but I can't do this for my function with AND clause:

function changeMap() {

```
    var dzialka = document.getElementById('dzialka').value;
    var symbol = document.getElementById('symbol').value;
    var where = '';

    if (dzialka) {
      dzialka = dzialka.replace(/'/g, '\\\'');
      where = "'NUMER' CONTAINS IGNORING CASE '" +
          dzialka + "'";
    }

    if (symbol) {
      if (dzialka) {
        where += ' AND ';
      }
      where += "SYMBOL_OG = '" + symbol + "'";
    }

    layer.setOptions({
      query: {
        select: locationColumn,
        from: tableid,
        where: where
      }
    });
  }
```

Can someone help me? I will be grateful for your help.

Trebor

Answer (score 0):

It is definitely possible to do what you want to do, but it's not that easy. In the example the location to pan to is calculated by the [Google Geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/) using an address. But you don't really *have* the address (i.e. content of `locationColumn`) in your JavaScript code. It depends what kind of information you store in the `locationColumn`, I suppose it's some kind of address that can be geocoded.

Therefore you have to send a select statement directly to Fusion Tables. Google Fusion Tables has a JSONP interface that you can use for this purpose.

```
var gftUrl = 'http://www.google.com/fusiontables/api/query?';
var jsonUrlTail = '&jsonCallback=?';
var query = 'select ' + locationColumn + ' from ' + tableid + ' where ' + where;
var params = "sql=" + encodeURI(query + jsonUrlTail);

var myCallback = function(data,status) {
    if(status !== 'success') {
        window.alert('Call to Google Fusion Tables failed: ' + status);
        return;
    }
    var address = data.table.rows[0][0];

    /* start code from google example */
    geocoder.geocode({
    address: address
    }, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
      map.setZoom(10);

      // OPTIONAL: run spatial query to find results within bounds.
      var sw = map.getBounds().getSouthWest();
      var ne = map.getBounds().getNorthEast();
      var where = 'ST_INTERSECTS(' + locationColumn +
          ', RECTANGLE(LATLNG' + sw + ', LATLNG' + ne + '))';
      layer.setOptions({
        query: {
          select: locationColumn,
          from: tableId,
          where: where
        }
      });
    } else {
      window.alert('Address could not be geocoded: ' + status);
    }
    });
    /* end code from google example */
}

var jqxhr = $.post(gftUrl, params, myCallback, "jsonp"); /* jsonp parameter is very important */
```

In this example I use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) for the [`$.post` function](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/).

Comment: Have a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10206033/search-in-fusion-tables-and-zoom-to-results/10211253#10211253) to a very similar question. This uses the Google Visualization API and is maybe a simpler solution.