# How can I load a Fusion Tables csv from a client application?

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, actionscript-2, google-fusion-tables

I was just playing with Google Fusion Tables and I was wondering how I could load a csv from the client side. So far I've tried several options:

From actionscript 3.0:

```
var r:URLRequest = new URLRequest("https://www.google.com/fusiontables/exporttable?query=select%20*%20from%203685185%20");
r.method = URLRequestMethod.GET;
var l:URLLoader = new URLLoader(r);
l.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,loaded);
l.addEventListener(HTTPStatusEvent.HTTP_STATUS,onHTTPStatus);

function onHTTPStatus(event:HTTPStatusEvent):void{
    trace(event.status);
}
function loaded(event:Event):void{
    trace(this.loaderInfo.url,event.target.data);
}
```

From actionscript 2.0:

```
var vars:LoadVars = new LoadVars();
vars.onLoad = function(loaded):Void{
    if(loaded) trace(unescape(this));
    else       trace("error loading data");
}
vars.onHTTPStatus = function(status:Number):Void{
    trace(status);
}
vars.load("http://www.google.com/fusiontables/exporttable?query=select%20*%20from%203685185%20&r="+new Date().getMilliseconds());
```

From javascript:

```
$.get('https://www.google.com/fusiontables/exporttable?query=select%20*%20from%203685185%20',
    function(data) { alert(data); });
```

In actionscript everything works in the standalone player, but not online which smells like some sort of security sandbox issue. 
In [JS](http://lifesine.eu/test/fusiontable.html) I get this:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://www.google.com/fusiontables/exporttable?query=select%20*%20from%203685185%20. Origin http://lifesine.eu is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

The table I'm querying is public and exportable. I've also tried the call using Simple REST Client on Chrome and got the right response. Any hints on how what I might be missing ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can only speak to the javascript approach.  You need to use JSONP to retrieve the results due to browser cross domain access restrictions. Luckily Fusion Tables supports JSONP.  I posted some example code in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9778985/1211981).  Another approach would be to use the google.visualization library and there's some sample code in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10211253/1211981).

**UPDATE**
@george-profenza

2 points. The URL for the FT JSONP api is different.  And for jsonp you must add a callback parameter.  Try this:

```
var queryurl = 'https://fusiontables.googleusercontent.com/fusiontables/api/query?sql=select%20*%20from%203685185%20&jsonCallback=?';
```

Also here's an example success function:

```
 function dataHandler(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
     alert(textStatus);
     var cols = data.table.cols;
     var rows = data.table.rows;
     for (var i = 0; i < cols.length; i++) {
         alert(cols[i]);
     }
     for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
         for(j=0; j < rows[i].length; j++) {
             alert(rows[i][j]);
          }
     }
}
```

Comment: [tried it](http://lifesine.eu/test/fusiontable.html) but it didn't work using your 1st answer. I don't have a lot of experience with js, am I doing it wrong ?

Comment: That worked perfectly! Thanks! _(note it also works in actionscript removing `&jsonCallback=?`)_