# how to save the results of visualization table as excel

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-fusion-tables

I am using visualization api for showing my fusion table on my web page.Now i want to save or download the table as excel data.I have added query capabilities to that fusion table in my web page.So querying the data will display new result everytime.So i want to save those results as excel.Help me.

Answer (score 1):

I posted an [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10441491/1211981) which should allow you to do this.  Of course your web page cannot save to the users hard-drive, but you can put up a link which allow the user to save a CSV file which is Excel compatible.

Comment: where to add those code in my page.My fusion table id is 4080920.Tell me where to add this code in my html page.

Comment: @baji What's your web page url? The one where you "added query capabilities".