# search and zoom Fusion table map to a particular point

Tags: search, google-maps-api-3, zooming, google-fusion-tables, layer

I have a sample fusion table map layer with a search box. I want to serach a particular location in fusion table using that box and zoom to that point. The autocomplete in serach box is working perfectly but the zoom to a particular point is doesn't working. Is there any other method to fix it? My fusion table [link is here](https://www.google.com/fusiontables/data?docid=16SYU_z59qRPK_uYF7FeLdV2Hj0ODSoKIIb3Jad8).

Comment: By the way my map code is [fiddled here](http://jsfiddle.net/ppsSH/)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Search in Fusion Tables and Zoom to results](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10206033/search-in-fusion-tables-and-zoom-to-results)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to understand the format of the data in your FusionTable.  You are using geoxml3 to parse it as if it was KML, but it is a two column location (Latitude/Longitude).  For that format, query for both those columns, and use the results to center and zoom the map (you don't need geoxml3).

```
            if(searchString == "") {
                var query="SELECT 'Lat','Long' FROM " + tableid;
            }
            else {
                var query="SELECT 'Lat','Long' FROM " + tableid + " WHERE 'Station Name' = '" + searchString + "'";
            }
            zoom2query(query);
```

and:

```
        function zoomTo(response) {
            if (!response) {
                alert('no response');
                return;
            }
            if (response.isError()) {
                alert('Error in query: ' + response.getMessage() + ' ' + response.getDetailedMessage());
                return;
            } 
            var lat = response.getDataTable().getValue(0,0);
            var lng = response.getDataTable().getValue(0,1);
            var zoom_level = 15;
            var location = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng);
            map.setCenter(location);
            map.setZoom(zoom_level);
        }
```

[working example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_SO_FusionTables_zoom2autocomplete.html)

Comment: I removed the geoxml3 parser from my code & updated the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ppsSH/1/). But I am struggling with querying for two column location. Can i get some sample code?